# Python Class to Return a Dictionary

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I researched online and still am having a hard time understanding how to create classes. The examples in SoloLearn, DataCamp, and other sites often use the `Person` / `Employee` example, such as this one:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.firstname = first
        self.lastname = last

    def Name(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname

class Employee(Person):

    def __init__(self, first, last, staffnum):
        Person.__init__(self,first, last)
        self.staffnumber = staffnum

    def GetEmployee(self):
        return self.Name() + ", " +  self.staffnumber

x = Person("Marge", "Simpson")
y = Employee("Homer", "Simpson", "1007")

print(x.Name())
print(y.GetEmployee())
```

I am trying to create an example class that returns a dictionary by modifying it slightly. Here is the code:

```
 class Place:

    def __init__(self, country, province):
        self.country= country
        self.province = province

    def CountryState(self):
        return {
            'Province': self.province,
            'Country': self.country
            }

class Location(Place):

    def __init__(self, country, province, city, street, postal):
        super(Place, self).__init__(country, province, city, street, postal)
        self.city = city
        self.street = street
        self.postal = postal

    def GetLocation(self):
        return CountryState().update({
            'City': self.city,
            'Street': self.street,
            'Postal': self.postal
            })

if __name__=="__main__":

    x = Place('United States', "California")
    y = Location("United States", "California", "Los Angeles", "Johnson Street", "90007")

    print(x.CountryState())
    print(y.GetLocation())
```

I get a Traceback as follows using `pdb.set_trace()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/Python/class-example.py", line 37, in <module>
    y = Location("United States", "California", "Los Angeles", "Johnson Street", "90007")
  File "/home/john/Python/class-example.py", line 22, in __init__
    super(Place, self).__init__(country, province, city, street, postal)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
> /usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/run.py(370)runcode()
-> jit = self.rpchandler.console.getvar("<<toggle-jit-stack-viewer>>")
```

`pdb` `list`:

```
365                 self.usr_exc_info = sys.exc_info()
366                 if quitting:
367                     exit()
368                 # even print a user code SystemExit exception, continue
369                 print_exception()
370  ->             jit = self.rpchandler.console.getvar("<<toggle-jit-stack-viewer>>")
371                 if jit:
372                     self.rpchandler.interp.open_remote_stack_viewer()
373             else:
374                 flush_stdout()
375
```

I haven't been able to get `__init__` to accept parameters. Please let me know what I am missing so I can return the dictionary from these lines:

```
print(x.CountryState())
print(y.GetLocation())

{ 'Country': 'United States', 'State': 'California' }

{ 'Country': 'United States', 'City': 'Los Angeles', 'Street':'Johnson Street', 'Postal Code': '90007'}
```

Comment: You're using super incorrectly, it should be `super(Location, self)`; you pass the class that gets skipped, not the one that gets called (because the whole point is you don't have to know which class that is).

Comment: You also shouldn't be passing `city`, `street` and `postal` to the super constructor. It takes 2 arguments, not 5.

Comment: Next, `return CountryState()` should be `return self.CountryState()`, and finally, `dict.update` returns `None`, so your `GetLocation` method is fairly useless. See [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38987). I'm voting to close as too broad, seeing how there were 4 separate issues to fix.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Location(Place)` class you are calling

```
super(Place, self).__init__(country, province, city, street, postal)
```

You should call the super-class of the `Location` class. Now, you are calling the super class of `Place`. Since `Place` has no declared superclass, it derives from `object` class (which is the parent of all classes), and you are calling the `object` constructor, which takes no parameters.

Also, even if you fix that, you are giving more parameters than `Place` takes. The correct form would be

```
super(Location, self).__init__(country, province)
```